# QGIS Madeira does not connect to WMTS service

Tags: qgis, wmts

Working with a new laptop HP zbook and Windows 10.
QGIS Madeira doesn't connect to any WMS service.

> Error: 2019-03-14T09:57:34     CRITICAL    Ongeldige Laag : Raster
>   layer Provider is ongeldig (provider: wms, URI:
>   tileMatrixSet=EPSG:28992&crs=EPSG:28992&layers=2016_ortho25&styles=default&format=image/jpeg&url=https://geodata.nationaalgeoregister.nl/luchtfoto/rgb/wmts?request%3DGetCapabilities%26service%3DWMTS)
>
> 2019-03-19T10:26:05     WARNING    Downloaden van capabilities
>   mislukt: Error creating SSL context (unsupported protocol)

Up to now I worked with Windows 7 without any problem.

Does anyone recognise this problem?

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18894056/error-creating-ssl-context-qt for a possible solution

Comment: This sounds like more of a general computer problem than a GIS-specific problem. You may have better luck asking on stackoverflow.

Comment: Using just `https://geodata.nationaalgeoregister.nl/luchtfoto/rgb/wmts?` as the WMTS URL works for me on Windows with 64 bit QGIS  3.4.3-Madeira

Answer (score 1):

I just used the WMS [URL](https://geodata.nationaalgeoregister.nl/luchtfoto/rgb/wmts?request%3DGetCapabilities%26service%3DWMTS) you posted on my QGIS 3.4.5 Madeira and it works. I searched a little bit more and came to this [link](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/253725/cannot-seem-connect-to-wms-server). I tested the URL you showed and the certificate is valid. Can you test it on your computer? I guess it is something network related and would check firewalls and antivirus packages.

Comment: Yes I have. Also tried the 32 version. Same problem.